# What is the replacement for KeyStore API in jetty http client?

Tags: jetty

All the keystore related methods are marked as deprecated in Jetty docs but it does not refer to the replacement API. What API should be used instead?

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ssl context factory instead. e.g.

```
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        URL keyStoreUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("XXXXXX.pfx");

        URL trustStoreUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("XXXX.jks");

        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("pkcs12");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStoreType("jks");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStore(keyStoreUrl.toString());
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(KEY_STORE_PASS);

        sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        sslContextFactory.setValidateCerts(false);
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStore(trustStoreUrl.toString());
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(KEY_STORE_PASS);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(KEY_STORE_PASS);


        httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
```